# SQL Server: Selecting range of values from a table and doing calculation on them

Tags: sql, sql-server, range, case

I have this table

[image]

which has 3 columns

```
Machine Name | memory | date
```

I would like to:

1. Select average of those memory if memory values are certain ranges
2. I want to know how frequent it hits that range

Here's my crack at it but it :

```
SELECT
    MachineName, 
    CASE 
       WHEN Memory >= 75 AND Memory < 85 
          THEN AVG(Memory) AS Memory75to85,
               COUNT((MachineName)) AS Frequency75to85,
       WHEN Memory >= 85 AND Memory < 95 
          THEN AVG(Memory) AS Memory85to95,
               COUNT((MachineName)) AS Frequency85to95 
       WHEN Memory >= 95 AND Memory <= 100
          THEN AVG(Memory) AS Memory95to100,
               COUNT((MachineName)) AS Frequency95to100
       ELSE
          0, CounterDateTime
    END
FROM 
    Table
GROUP BY 
    MachineName
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The column result I want is:

```
| Name | Memory75to85 | Frequency75to85 | Memory85to95 | Frequency85to95 | Memory95to100 | Frequency95to100 | date |
```

Anyone care to help?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: | Name |Memory75to85| Frequency75to85 | Memory85to95 | Frequency85to95 |Memory95to100 | Frequency95to100| date |

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to use here is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    MachineName,
    CounterDateTime,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Memory >= 75 AND Memory < 85 THEN Memory END) AS Memory75to85,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Memory >= 75 AND Memory < 85 THEN 1 END) AS Frequency75to85,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Memory >= 85 AND Memory < 95 THEN Memory END) AS Memory85to95,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Memory >= 85 AND Memory < 95 THEN 1 END) AS Frequency85to95,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Memory >= 95 AND Memory <= 100 THEN Memory END) AS Memory95to100,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Memory >= 95 AND Memory <= 100 THEN 1 END) AS Frequency95to100
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    MachineName,
    CounterDateTime;
```

One major problem with your current approach is that a `CASE` expression has to generate a single scalar value; it can't output two different values.  So in the query above, we take conditional averages and counts based on the memory range to generate the output you want.

Comment: I've tried this but I'm getting a NULL value for the average. The frequency is correct but not the average.

Comment: Please add sample data.

Comment: Actually, I've figured the error. This one should be  <95 AVG(CASE WHEN Memory >= 85 AND Memory < 95 THEN Memory END) AS Memory85to95,

Comment: Sorry...easy to make a typo without proper testing.

Comment: No worries! Thank you. I'm here to test. Hahah you provided the answer, its least I could do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using conditional aggregation like below -

```
Select  
   MachineName, 
   avg(CASE WHEN Memory >=75 AND Memory <85 THEN Memory end) AS Memory75to85,
   count(CASE WHEN Memory >=75 AND Memory <85 THEN MachineName end) AS Frequency75to85,
   avg(case when Memory >=85 AND Memory <95 THEN Memory end) AS Memory85to95,
   count(case when Memory >=85 AND Memory <95 THEN MachineName end) AS Frequency85to95 
   avg(case WHEN Memory >=95 AND Memory <=100 THEN Memory end) AS Memory95to100,
   count(case WHEN Memory >=95 AND Memory <=100 THEN MachineName end) AS Frequency95to100,
   cast(CounterDateTime as date) as Date
From Table
Group by MachineName,cast(CounterDateTime as date)
```